# JwtBuilder add \ to my Json String - Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, jwt

I have a JSON string (made by Jackson to convert an object):

```
String my_JSON_String = {"id":-1,"id_contratto":1,"datetime_inizio":"2018-09-15 17:44:02","datetime_fine":null,"numero_chiamate_individuali":-1,"minuti_totali_chiamate_individuali":1421,"numero_chiamate_gruppo":3027,"minuti_totali_chiamate_gruppo":-1,"numero_messaggi_individuali_testo":-1,"numero_messaggi_individuali_multimediali":-1,"numero_messaggi_gruppo_testo":-1,"numero_messaggi_gruppo_multimediali":-1,"numero_eventi_inviati":-1,"numero_interventi_creati":-1,"enabled":false}
```

I have to put this string inside a custom field called "DATI" of the claim of a JWT. I use:

```
JwtBuilder MY_JwtBuilder = Jwts.builder()
                .setIssuedAt( new Date() )
                .setIssuer("Fausto")
                .setSubject("Ciao")
                .claim("DATI", my_JSON_String ) 
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "DonalDuck");
String JWT=  MY_JwtBuilder.compact();
```

If I test JWT putting it in https://jwt.io/, I get the following string:

```
{
  "iat": 1537026243,
  "iss": "Fausto",
  "sub": "Ciao",
  "DATI": "{\"id\":-1,\"id_contratto\":1,\"datetime_inizio\":\"2018-09-15 17:44:02\",\"datetime_fine\":null,\"numero_chiamate_individuali\":-1,\"minuti_totali_chiamate_individuali\":1421,\"numero_chiamate_gruppo\":3027,\"minuti_totali_chiamate_gruppo\":-1,\"numero_messaggi_individuali_testo\":-1,\"numero_messaggi_individuali_multimediali\":-1,\"numero_messaggi_gruppo_testo\":-1,\"numero_messaggi_gruppo_multimediali\":-1,\"numero_eventi_inviati\":-1,\"numero_interventi_creati\":-1,\"enabled\":false}",
  "exp": 1537029843
}
```

It was added a \ for each quotation mark inside the field DATI. Thi is a problem in the web site side.
How to avoid the adding of \ ?

Thanks, Fausto

Comment: @benjamin c   May be you can help here?

Comment: I think the first line can't be your real code, that's not a string. I guess you produce it with `JSONObject.getString()` or something like that or you omitted the enclosing `""`, right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that you already create a string from your DATI object. 
The JWTBuilder treats it just as a string and escapes the `"` inside with `\`.

Instead of creating a JSON-String on your own, create a JSON object and pass that object as a parameter to `claim` and let the `JWTBuilder` take care of the correct serialization of that object,
e.g.:

```java
JSONObject datiClaim = new JSONObject();
datiClaim.put("id", -1);
datiClaim.put("id_contratto", 1);

...

JwtBuilder MY_JwtBuilder = Jwts.builder()
            .setIssuedAt( new Date() )
            .setIssuer("Fausto")
            .setSubject("Ciao")
            .claim("DATI", datiClaim ) 
....
```

Comment: I'll try, but I have in this case another problem: is there a way to create a JSONObject by a generic object? I mean that the object that I have to send in a JWT could me of different classes. Is there a way do do it? For example I get I Json String by Jackson library starting from a whatever object... Can I do the same in order to create a JSON object?

Comment: In any case, apart the other problem in my comment, your solution work!!!

Comment: According to the [docs](http://javadox.com/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt/0.4/io/jsonwebtoken/JwtBuilder.html#claim-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) the second paramter of `claim` can be anything of type `object`, so basically you don't even need the `JSONObject` but can pass any other object type directly.

Comment: @jps This is actually true, thank you for this comment. There is no need to convert it to json, it accepts any Java object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#replaceAll()` with a pattern of `^\"|\"$`

E.g.

```
String JWT = MY_JwtBuilder.compact().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
```

Comment: JWT is encrypted, is something like "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1MzcwMjczMjcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6Ly9mcDJ0ZWNoLml0LyIsInN1YiI6IkVUSVAvbnVsbCIsIkRBVEkiOiJ7J2lkJzotMSwnaWRfY29udHJhdHRvJzoyLCdkYXRldGltZV9pbml6aW8nOicyMDE4LTA5LTE1IDE4OjAyOjA3JywnZGF0ZXRpbWVfZmluZSc6bnVsbCwnbnVtZXJvX2NoaWFtYXRlX2luZGl2aWR1YWxpJzotMSwnbWludXRpX3RvdGFsaV9jaGlhbWF0ZV9pbmRpdmlkdWFsaSc6Mjk4MCwnbnVtZXJvX2NoaWFtYXRl...."; it doesn't make any sense the substitution in the encrypted string.